# Match key and value of splitted Boundary

Tags: node.js, regex, split, match, form-fields

```
request.on('end', function () {
   if (request.headers.hasOwnProperty('content-type') && request.headers['content-type'].indexOf('boundary=') > -1) {
       var parts = request.headers['content-type'].split('boundary=');
       var boundary = parts[1];
       var splitBody = requestBody.split(boundary);

       console.log(splitBody);
       res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });
       res.write(JSON.stringify({ formFields: splitBody }));
   }
   else {
       //bad request
       res.writeHead(400, { "Content-Type": "text/paint" });
       res.write("missing boundary in content-type ");
       }
});
```

So I get this (console.log):

```
[ '--',
'\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="image"\r\n\r\n/ap.jpg\r\n--',
'\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="name"\r\n\r\nsmth\r\n--',
'--\r\n' ]
```

So basically what I want to do is iterate over splitBody and match the key and value and add it to array of fields. What is the best way to do that?

So basically instead of this:

```
'\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="image"\r\n\r\n/ap.jpg\r\n--',
```

it should be this:

```
image=ap.jpg
```

and that should be added

Comment: show the desired result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest see edit

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest any ideas?

Comment: I guess, there should be something (built-in) to strip newlines from `requestBody` beforehand

Answer (score 0):

Just splitting by boundary is not enough if you need to extract content part names and contents as an array of pairs. You need to elaborate a regular expression to match and capture the name and the content and iterate trough matches to extract these pairs:

```
...........................
var boundary = parts[1];
var re = new RegExp("--" + boundary + "\r\n(?:.+name=\"([^\"]+)\".*\r\n)(?:.+\r\n)*\r\n" 
    + "((?:.+\r\n)*.+)(?=\r\n--" + boundary + ")", "g");
var match = re.exec(requestBody);
var fields = [];
while (match) {
    var field = {};
    field[match[1]] = match[2];
    fields.push(field);
    match = re.exec(requestBody);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify({ formFields: fields }))
res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });
res.write(JSON.stringify({ formFields: fields }));
...........................
```

To explain the regex I'll assume `boundary === "QWERTY"` for the sake of simplicity. In this case the regex is:

```
--QWERTY\r\n(?:.+name="([^"]+)".*\r\n)(?:.+\r\n)*\r\n((?:.+\r\n)*(?:.+))(?=\r\n--QWERTY)
```

Explanation:

1. The actual boundary is composed from the `Content-Type`'s `boundary` value by prepending `\r\n--` and appending `\r\n` to it. Hence `--QWERTY\r\n` at the start of the regex.
2. Each part in a multipart HTTP message has a header, which is a series of non-empty strings (`(?:.+\r\n)*`) immediately following a boundary and ending with an empty string (`(?:.+\r\n)*\r\n`).
3. The first line of a part header contains `name="value"` pair which defines a name we're interested in. This can be matched with `(?:.+name=\"([^\"]+)\".*\r\n)`. Notice the first capture group here (`([^\"]+)`) - this is the name of our interest.
4. After the part header we've got the part contents which is again a series of non-empty lines (`(?:.+\r\n)*`) with the last line not including `\r\n` (belonging to the next boundary). So the last line is matched with `.+` (non-capturing group) and the whole part contents is `((?:.+\r\n)*.+)`. This is also in a capture group since we need this particular bit a a field value.
5. We need to end our part with boundary `(?=\r\n--QWERTY)` but it should be matched using zero-length lookahead to let this boundary match at the next regex `exec()`.

Simplified Node.js demo: https://ideone.com/fQN2hB